# cocoapods not installed or not in valid state using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cocoapods, arm64

i'm developing an ios app with

m1(apple silicon) + Android studio + flutter + ios15(simulator)

after install url_launcher in project, i got error when build app.

i tried a lot of things

1. deleted caches of IDE
2. re-installed cocoapods with gem
3. re-installed with "arch -x86_64 pod install...etc"
4. restart android studio

application worked before install url_launcher..
url_launcher doesn't make trouble with web and android platform

what should i have to do??!!

message is like...

[image]

Comment: have you tried running `flutter run` ?

Answer (score 0):

From Danny's comment, "flutter run" in the terminal sovled my issue right away

*ps
I've tried everything, but that only sovled the issues.
I think the debug tool provided in VSCode need some update with url_launcher. Somehow they cannot detect the cocoapods after adding url_launcher in dependency. Anyway, "flutter run" works best!

Answer (score 0):

flutter clean
flutter run

Worked for me! Not sure why I don't try this first every time there is an issue.